# Vaccination boosters - is their precise timing important?

Tags: vaccination

Booster vaccines are typically booked exactly 4 weeks after the prime dose, is it known how important this specific time window is? How is vaccine efficacy changed if boosters are given later than schedule?

The vaccines I am particularly interested in are DTaP/IPV/Hib/HepB, MenB (Bexsero) and PCV (for diphteria, tetanus, pertussis, polio, haemophilus influenza type B, hepatitis B, meningococcal group B, pneumococcal infection), which are usually administrated from 8 weeks of age onward.

Comment: You should always get personal medical advice from your physician - call your doctor's office if you are wondering about vaccine schedules. I've tried to edit your question to come from a more general perspective that could be on-topic, however you shouldn't use answers to the question as a substitute for medical advice from your physician.

Comment: @BryanKrause thank you for your comment. I am not looking for a substitute of personal medical advice... We will talk to the GP. I just wanted to get other people's thoughts on this matter as there is very little definitive information online. Are there studies or reference materials I can refer to?

Comment: I know little about the details of vaccine schedule recommendations otherwise I'd answer your question. My assumption is that for reasons of practicality, most likely the vaccines were initially studied on some schedule; since that schedule was shown effective, that schedule is now used. It's likely that any further study is fairly limited in scope - you would either need to administer vaccines off-schedule (ethics issues) or study cases of off-schedule use (rare/hard to recruit). You could refer to the US CDC or UK NHS for guidelines, but they might not have a lot of detail.